# "Add to cart" ajax button on DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am started to use [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) because they provide what I need: ready to use pagination, ready to use how many items to show on the table `10`, `25` .. etc. And here is the first problem. I want to put one button `Add to cart` at the end and with ajax to place items in basket which will downloaded later as zip. So far I was able to put the button but I'm very new in ajax and jquery stuff and can't figured out how to do the cart things. Here is what I have:

The table:

```
<table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>№</th>
                            <th>Program</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>                                
                            <th>Add to Cart</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

Here is how I put the custom button at the end

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "response.php", 
    "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "aTargets": [5],
        "mData": null,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return '<a href="#" id="total_items" onclick="(\''+ full[0] +'\');">Add to cart</a>';
        }            

    }]
 });
});
```

How I trying to put them in the cart

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'store_items.php',
    data:{
      total_cart_items:"totalitems"
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

});

function cart(id)
{
  var ele=document.getElementById(upload_id);
  var upload_title=document.getElementById("upload_title").value;
  var upload_description=document.getElementById("upload_description").value;

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'store_items.php',
    data:{
      upload_title:upload_title,
      upload_description:upload_description
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

}

function show_cart()
{
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'store_items.php',
  data:{
    showcart:"cart"
  },
  success:function(response) {
    document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
    $("#mycart").slideToggle();
  }
 });

}
```

and the php part

```
  session_start();

if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))
{
    echo count($_SESSION['upload_title']);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['upload_title']))
{
    $_SESSION['upload_title'][]=$_POST['upload_title'];
    $_SESSION['upload_description'][]=$_POST['upload_description'];    
    echo count($_SESSION['upload_title']);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['showcart']))
{
   for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['upload_title']);$i++)
   {
       echo "<div class='cart_items'>";      
       echo "<p>".$_SESSION['upload_title'][$i]."</p>";
       echo "<p>".$_SESSION['upload_description'][$i]."</p>";
       echo "</div>";
   }
   exit();  
}
```

So far the main problem that I see is how to pass the ID of the item which I store in cart. On the datatable ID of the item is on the first №. Then I'm not sure how to pass it to the cart with this ajax.
If need I can show also the php part of `response.php` from where the table is populated.

Comment: why do you have 3 ajax calls?\

Comment: I've added it but here is the problem.. how to take `upload_id` when it is coming from `response.php`

Comment: @madalinivascu because it is adding items do the cart and above form I have a place where again via ajax showing the items in cart.

Comment: @Sougata I don't get it what I forgot?

Comment: wich of the 3 ajax function do you use for your link?

Comment: I think the function which is responsible for this is `function cart(id)`.. BTW this is the original tutorial which I trying to implement: [This is the tutorial](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/demo_simple-add-to-cart-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php.php) .. without the fancy buttons and etc. Just add to cart and keep items in cart..

Comment: your problem seems to be here`return '<a href="#" id="total_items" onclick="(\''+ full[0] +'\');">Add to cart</a>';`

Comment: Yes, I know.. as I said I don't know in this case how to put `upload_id` on that button.

Comment: @BStud What does `console.log(full[0])` on `mrender` callback returning? I seem can't understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: All I want is to add button `add to cart` on each row. When I click on this button I want to save this row in some kind cart. Then if I click on another row of the table `add to cart` to add this row also in the cart. In the end I will go to this cart and download all rows(which will be documents pdf's, docs...). Like shopping cart in online shops but for a files.

Comment: Where to put this `console.log(full[0])`?

Comment: The MAJOR problem here is that I don't know how to take the ID of the row i.e. the ID of this record and to put it on the button here `return '<a href="#" id="total_items" onclick="(\''+ full[0] +'\');">Add to cart</a>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `MAJOR` problem with getting ID you can make this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": "response.php", 
   "aoColumnDefs": [
   {
      "aTargets": [5],
      "mData": null,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#' + full[0] + '>' + 'Add to Cart' + '</a>';
      }
    }            

    }]
   });
 });
```

The mRender Function takes three parameters:

> data = The data for this cell, as defined in mData
>
> type = The datatype
> (can be ignored mostly)
>
> full = The full data array for this row.

Comment: Ok, this is working for the button. Now the question is how to wrap each row  in some div or how to take each row number and pass it to the `store_items.php`